# Which way to alter commands is more robust/sustainable

Tags: macros, titlesec, best-practices, etoolbox, patching

I have a general question. If I'm writing a .cls file (or a package file, as well), what's the best way to edit standard commands like `\section` which are defined by the used standard class or latex.ltx?

In this hypothetic case, for example, I could use a package like `titlesec`, or the `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox`, or do a complete redefinition with `RenewDocumentCommand`/`renewcmand`.

Which of these possibilities is the most robust respectively most save way to alter such a command, and why? If I had to guess, I would say its the most simplistic way with renewing, because it needs less additional packages, but I may be wrong.

**Edit**

Because my question may have been a little bit to unspecific, I try to make it clearer.

Assuming I'm writing a class file which provides the layout of a specific journal and, in best case, can be added to CTAN. If I want to change the styling of sectioning commands in such a case, but of course preserve aspects like numbering, ToC etc. What would be the most robust/savest way in such a scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is borderline opinion based, although it's not an unreasonable question. From a maintenance perspective, reducing package dependencies is almost always a good thing, but it really depends of what your intended user base is, and which packages you are depending on.

Comment: You're right. Therefore I updated my question to make it a little bit more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Still opinion based, but too long for a comment.

`\renewcommand` is far more readable and rather safe, if you start from the standard definition and make your changes, taking care to preserve  the whole structure which provides the numbering etc. features as requested by OP and discussed in @enkorvaks answer.

Nevertheless, I prefer to use `etoolbox`'s `patchcmd` for small changes (like e.g. `\large`->`\Large`) for better compatibility. And in the case of a large project loading many packages, it is rather  unlikely that `etoolbox` it not anyway loaded by them.

As an example, in most of my custom `.sty` or `.cls`, based on the standard `book` ckass,  I use `\renewcommand` for significant changes in `chapter`s
(in fact in `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead`), but `\patchcmd` for slight modifications of `\section` and `\subsection` (assuming that one understand how LaTeX's `\@startsection` works with its 6 argumemts).

And, oppositely to many posts on this site, I would recommand to never use `titlesec`/`titleformat`, that breaks several things, the worse (for my use case) being incompatibility with `minitoc`.

Another important thing is to make the changes early enough, especially before the loading of `hyperref` and many others that also alter the sectioning commands but are not usually listed in the packages to be loaded  "very late", as the former is.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It goes in the direction I also probably would move. `titlesec` etc. is more for fast changes on the user side. And for cls styles one should prefer more *basic* commands. But are there situations where a command patched by `etoolbox` will *break* easier than one fully renewed?

Comment: AFAIK, no, as long as the command you intend to patch have not been previously modified in an unexpected  an incompatible way. In this sense  a .cls would be better than a .sty as it ensure that YOUR changes are done FIRST..

Comment: The `titletoc` package which is by the same author as `titlesec` and therefore compatible, provides the same functionality as `minitoc`.

Comment: For my cls file I decided to use `renewcommand` for the sections. So I could provide my layout but still keep them editable through a package like `titlesec`, if possible users want to change something for their specific document.

Answer (score 1):

As Alan Munn notes in his comment, "It depends." For a style (`.sty`) I would suggest using a package, since your `.sty` could be used with almost any class, and redefining a "standard" command will lead to many things not behaving in a way that the document author may expect. The `\section` command does far more than set the font to a larger size, make it bold, and make it sanserif. If you `\renewcommand` or `\RenewDocumentCommand` the `\section` command to (for example) `{\Large \textbf{\textsf{#1}}}`, you lose all ability to make a Table of Contents (and internal references to headings, and section numbers, and ...).

If you are writing your own class for your own use, and never intend to release it, choose the easiest option for you that does what you want.

If you are writing your own class (`.cls` file) to be released for the public to use, make the `\section` command at least comparable to the standard one (that is, numbering as needed, style as you want it, table of contents, references). There are packages which handle all of this complex detail for you,
which means that you don't need to consider all of the edge-cases and bits *you* don't use, but others might.

#### TLDR:

There are many edge cases and uses that you may not notice because you don't use them. Others might (and probably do). A well-written existing package takes care of that so you don't have to.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Of course, I'm aware that its not a good option to renew a standard command only for styling purpose. I edited my question, so its a little bit clearer ;)